# Expectation[] not working for relatively simple expression under lognormal distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am trying to find the expectation of a relatively simple expression under a lognormal distribution with mean [Mu] - [Sigma]^2/2 and variance [Sigma]^2 , but it hangs for a long while and eventually returns the original question:

```
In[36]:= Expectation[(2 Sqrt[x])/(x + 1) - 1, 
 x \[Distributed] 
  LogNormalDistribution[ (\[Mu] - \[Sigma]^2/2), \[Sigma]]]

Out[36]= Expectation[-1 + (2 Sqrt[x])/(1 + x), 
 x \[Distributed] 
  LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu] - \[Sigma]^2/2, \[Sigma]]]
```

I have tried putting an Abs[] around the Sqrt[] to only take the positive root just in case that was the issue, without success. I have also tried adding Assumptions to the effect that x>0, [Sigma] > 0 but that made no difference.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are effectively asking Mathematica to integrate: $$\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{x}}{x+1}-1\right) e^{-\frac{\left(-2
   \mu +\sigma ^2+2 \log (x)\right)^2}{8 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{2
   \pi } \sigma  x}}dx$$ This integral is too difficult so it's giving up.

Comment: Just curious:  are you sure about wanting `LogNormalDistribution[\[Mu] - \[Sigma]^2/2, \[Sigma]]` ?  I ask because the mean of that distribution is $e^\mu$ and the variance is $\left(e^{\sigma^2}-1\right) e^{2 \left(m-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)+\sigma^2}$ (not $\sigma^2$).  In other words your first sentence talks about the two values listed as if those are the mean and variance.  But the way *Mathematica* parameterizes things, those are just the two parameters.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done numerically:

```
f[\[Mu]_?NumericQ, \[Sigma]_?NumericQ] :=  NExpectation[(2 Sqrt[x])/(x + 1) - 1, 
x \[Distributed] LogNormalDistribution[ (\[Mu] - \[Sigma]^2/2), \[Sigma]]];
f[1, 2]
```

> `-0.295453`

Comment: +1 For formatting tools see [`link`](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1044/9362)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for all the helpful comments. On the variance, if you don't subtract Sigma^2/2 then the mean will not be mu. The variance I meant is the variance of log returns not the variance of returns, so that is OK.
I tried the numerical integration and it gives me useful results which I can plot and make sense of, which is very helpful. An analytical solution would be even better if I could get one.
Is there any way to tease an analytic answer out for the hard integral by breaking it up? I tried but it seems to give up as "too difficult" very early. For example, it can do the integral for 1/x, but it already starts to choke on 1/(1+x), which doesn't seem particularly complex...

Comment: This information should be added in your original question by editing it, or as a comment on another answer if appropriate. "Answers" on this site are not used to continue a conversation, but are really reserved for proposing a solving approach to the question.